# "what if" analysis

Tags: phrase-request

A researcher has analyzed a certain historic event, by checking what would happen if the participants in that event have done something differently.

What is a good word or phrase that describes this kind of analysis?

I currently have two options: "what-if" analysis, or "retrospective" analysis. Can you suggest a better option?

Comment: I don't think [retrospective analysis](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22retrospective+analysis%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is at all correct here - it's invariably used to mean *analysis made with the **benefit of hindsight*** (into what *did* happen, not what *might have* happened if a few pivotal factors had been different). A ["what-if" analysis](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+what+if+analysis%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) sounds fine to me, and there are thousands of relevant instances in that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What if analysis" is perfectly fine. Othere terms are "counterfactual analysis," as in George White' answer, or "alternative history."

Answer (score 4):

"Counterfactual" is is used to describe a scenario that is being analyzed but is not what, in fact, happened.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried these?

> causal analysis
>
> historic-causal analysis
>
> causal analysis on historic events
>
> retrospectively causal analysis

Answer (score 2):

*What if* is a perfectly respectable term, even in academic circles. Some years ago military historian Robert Cowley commissioned several very highly regarded scholars to contribute essays to a series of three books entitled *What If? The World’s Most Foremost Military Historians Imagine What Might Have Been*, *More What If? Eminent Historians Imagine What Might Have Been*, and *What Ifs? of American History*.

Another term frequently used for both scholarly conjecture and fictional works is *alternate* (or *alternative*) *history*. There is an article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_history) which you may find of interest, and a discussion forum at [alternatehistory.com](http://www.alternatehistory.com/).